# Why Bootstrap 4 Grid shows horizontal scroller below 623px? Is it a bug?

Tags: css, grid, bootstrap-4, scroller

Im using simple:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-11"></div>
    <div class="col-1"></div>
</div>
```

within a `.container-fluid` **div** and I'm wondering why the grid adds a horizontal scrollbar when the window **width** is below **623px**?

I'm trying to figure it out because I don't want this to happen in my project.

Someone knows anything about it?

Here is a [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/brankoleone/pen/GQYVXm) version to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

On your codepen, it is because the "Right" word is to big for the col-1.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the word "Right" doesn't fit into the `col-1` column when the window gets to that size. So, it overflows and that's why the horizontal scrollbar appears.

To fix the issue, you could use `col-auto` instead of `col-1`.

`col-auto` would make the column as narrow as it has to be in order to fit the content inside the column. That also means, that in that particular case, the column would simply get pushed down (when it doesn't fit) and you wouldn't get any horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: Even when words are removed, we see the same behavior!